# How can I create chain of callbacks in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, callback, closures

In javascript I can do following:

```
var some = 100;

var param1 = 1;
func1(param1, function(res1) {

    var param2 = res1 + some;
    func2(param2, function(res2) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

In php same:

```
$some = 100;

$param1 = 1;
func1($param1, function($res1) use ($some) {

    $param2 = $res1 + $some;
    func2($param2, function($res2) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

How can I do same thing in python?

................................................

Comment: Use the lambda statement, or pass the function object.

Comment: Curious, I did not think there was such thing as a "lambda statement" -- I knew about lambda _expressions_.  But sure enough the phrase [appears in the official Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html).  Pedantry aside, the  "bodies" of lambda expressions are indeed simple expressions.  They are not statements that can hold state in the manner the OP wants.  There are probably tricks to make them do so, but in general they are best avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass functions as arguments.

```
some = 100

def callback1(res1):
    param2 = res1 + some
    func2(param2, callback2)
def callback2(res2):
    ...

param1 = 1
func1(param1, callback1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you tagged `asynchronous` as well. Python is NOT `asynchronous`. But python functions are also first class objects just like javascript and php. So, you can do the same thing in python as well.

```
def func1(data, nextFunction = None):
    print data
    if nextFunction:
        nextFunction()

def func(data, nextFunction = None):
    print data
    nextFunction(data * 10)

func(1, func1)
```

**Output**

```
1
10
```

Inline function definitions are restricted in python but it is still possible with `lambda` functions. For example,

```
data = ["abcd", "abc", "ab", "a"]
print sorted(data, key = lambda x: len(x)) # Succinctly written as key = len
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first class objects in Python, and you can nest them as well.

EG:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

some = 100

param1 = 1

def func1(param1, function):
    param2 = res1 + some;
    def func2(param2, function):
        pass
    func2(param2, function)
```

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are just syntactic wrappers for "thing that can execute arbitrary code before and after another function."  That's what you're doing with a callback, and hey: flat is better than nested.

```
def func1(fn):
    def wrapped(arg):
        return fn(arg+1)
    return wrapped

def func2(fn):
    def wrapped(arg):
        return fn(arg+2)
    return wrapped

@func1
@func2
def func3(x):
    return x + 3

print(func3(1))
#prints 7
```